# Can't pip install virtualenv on Windows 10 for Python, version doesn't satisfy, no matching distribution

Tags: python, pip, windows-10, virtualenv, virtual-environment

When attempting to install the virtualenv package I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\user>pip install virtualenv
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virtualenv (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for virtualenv
```

I'm using a basic user profile (not admin) on Windows 10, Python 3.8.2, pip 20.0.2, and the basic command prompt shell.

Comment: Try using ```pip install virtualenv=20.0.14```

Comment: Thanks, @AwesomeCronk! It ended up working the first way when I finished repairing VS and VS build tools.

Comment: Glad it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this will help future searchers, but the pip install worked after I finished modifying and repairing Visual Studio Community and Visual Studio Build Tools.

I had them modifying from the Visual Studio Installer in the background, removing unnecessary packages. Meanwhile, I ran the above virtualenv installation and got the error. After the VS modifications were complete, I ran repairs on both from the VS Installer because they hit some hiccups. Then, I tried `pip install virtualenv` again from the command prompt, and it worked.

I'm not sure why, but I think either the VS modify processes themselves were interrupting the pip install, or there were VS errors that needed to be repaired before virtualenv could install.

Comment: Also, using Anaconda/conda to create and manage environments is pretty great, probably better than pip.